# Blender viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I am learning Blender from a tutorial. I am following exactly what he is doing. But Still I notice some dissimilarities.

First his orthographic viewing is with a bracket says ‘Local’ mine doesn’t. but his ( the tutor’s) Transformation orientation is set to ‘Global’, mine too. Yet I dnt have local beside mine. Why?
Second his plane is (1), mine (95), what does this mean, and why we have so different numbers?
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi please use proper tags for your questions. The [tag:blender-internal-render-engine] is for questions about the legacy render engine *Blender Internal* that was shipped with Blender 2.79 and earlier versions.If you have questions about the 3D View please use the corresponding tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(local) means local view:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/local_view.html

The number in brackets means the current frame number.

Comment: Thank you.  I was confused.

Comment: @RussianBlue Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Okay. I will follow that.